# Unable to load class 'com.android.build.gradle.internal.ToolingRegistryProvider'

Tags: android-studio

Al instalar el Android Studio y ejecutar me sale directamente el siguiente error

> Unable to load class
>   'com.android.build.gradle.internal.ToolingRegistryProvider'

da opciones de recargar y reiniciar el android studio pero ninguna soluciona el problema...